# How to use angular templates in kendo ui

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to use kendo-ui controls with angular.
How can I use angular syntax in kendo templates?

[Here](http://jsbin.com/AriCANA/10/edit) is an example of two kendo ui list views, one with kendo ui template (works fine) and the second with angular template and it doesn't work.

**Additional explanation:**

In the example I have two kendo lists.
The first one is using the following template (kendo syntax):

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
<div class="product-view k-widget">
    <div class="edit-buttons">
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
    </div>
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <div class="listItem"><h3>#:ProductName#</h3></div>
</div>
```

the second list is using a template with angular syntax:

```
  <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="angularTemplate">
<div class="product-view k-widget">
    <div class="edit-buttons">
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
    </div>
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <div class="listItem"><h3>{{ProductName}}</h3></div>
</div>
```

The second one is not working. Either it is not supported or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down? You have a lot of code in the link!

Answer (score 2):

The latest build compiles templates with angular.

https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/issues/182